# HttpClient could not work

Tags: android, file-upload, httpclient

I download the httpmime.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpmimejar.htm

I put httpmime.jar in the folder of jre7/lib/ext/

It got a error [Multiple markers at this line] on below code

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```

Could you give some suggestion? Thanks

My reference android's code as below--------

```
 StringBuffer responseBody = new StringBuffer();  
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
 client.getParams().setParameter(
     CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);  
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://IP.IP.IP.IP/file_upload.php");  
 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
     HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
 entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody((FileObj), "application/zip")); 
 post.setEntity(entity);     
 ...
```

Comment: When you post code, you should indent so that it is easier to read. This can be done by pressing command k.

Comment: make sure you are performing the network connection on a separate thread. also post the logcat.

Comment: I fix it.  http://www.javaworld.com.tw/jute/post/view?bid=35&id=271664&sty=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things come to mind:

- Perform your network on separate thread
- make sure the `INTERNET` permission is set in your `Manifest.xml`

You should perform long tasks (such as network I/O) in separate thread from the main thread.  In fact depending on the version of Android you're developing for, the JVM will raise a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if you attempt to do networking on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. I did not add permission.

Comment: I use HTC one V cellphone. When I run my fileupload program,it show:sorry,fileupload was stopped. so it's not work. Could you give me some suggestion for debug? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are performing your network connection on a separate `Thread`, as described in this [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html). This is often the cause of weird errors like the one you are probably experiencing. Always make sure you perform potentially expensive operations on a separate `Thread` (i.e. using an `AsyncTask`) when developing applications for Android.